# Why the image slides to previous page in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am trying to pin an image on top of a page in a 2 column paper in MS Word 2013. My settings are these:

> Layout>Position>Vetical>Alignment>: Bottm relative to Top Margin.
>
> Layout>Position>Move object with text: Unchecked
>
> Layout>Position>Lock Anchor: Checked
>
> Layout>Text Wrapping>Wrapping Style: Top and Bottom

But every time I remove some text from previous pages, the image jumps onto previous page. Any idea?

Comment: would putting in a Page Break at the bottom of the previous page work?

Comment: Then it would make a white gap if I remove some text.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how both requirements can be met.  If you want the image to be on the top of the page, then you will conceivably have whitespace between the end of text of the previous page and the start of the next page.  You can't really have it both ways.

Comment: @Madball73 Well, there is some text after the image. I want to fill the gap by some of those texts. I don't want to do it by hand, I'm looking for a dynamic way to do this.